# Secure Handling of Auth Tokens with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, rails-api

I'm working on a new rails api project, and I'm trying to get to the best usability/security balance.

The user will establish a session by posting username/password to `api/v1/sessions`. For a valid user, it will create an authentication token, which is it's own activerecord model, associated by the polymorphic relationship authenticatable, giving me the flexibility to have multiple user models if I need to.

```
class AuthenticationToken < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :digest_token
  def self.from_authenticatable(authenticatable)
    self.create(authenticatable: authenticatable, token: generate_token)
  end
end
```

The undigested token (SecureRandom.hex) gets rendered back to the client via JSON to authenticate future requests. The token gets salted and digested for storage in the database using BCrypt and a configured work factor.

The client will provide the raw auth token and an identity (can be username or password) to load the user record. Authentication will be handled by `authenticate_with_http_token`

```
def authenticate_token
  authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
    user = User.identified_by(options["identity"])
    user.authentication_tokens.any? do |auth_token|
      @current_user = user if auth_token.secure_compare(token)
    end
  end
end
```

Auth tokens are compared via a constant time alogrithm lifted from devise.

If current user is not successfully set, I render 401 unauthorized.

I feel like this is reasonably secure, and the only thing I really want to do is add some more fields to the auth token to track where it was last used (user agent) to allow the user to revoke some of the auth tokens if they like.

Are there any major holes with this approach? Anything else I should consider?